# NodeJS: Actual native substitute for "through2" for intervention to steams in 2021

Tags: node.js, through2

From the [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) documentation:

> ### Do you need this?
>
> Since Node.js introduced Simplified Stream Construction, many uses of
> through2 have become redundant. Consider whether you really need to
> use through2 or just want to use the 'readable-stream' package, or the
> core 'stream' package (which is derived from 'readable-stream').

If I understand correctly, now (from 2021) we can intervene to the streams without third-party libraries.
I did not found how to do same thing as `through2` in [Stream documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_simplified_construction).

```js
// ...
  .pipe(through2(function (file, encoding, callback) {
    // Do something with file ...
    callback(null, file)
   }))

// ↑ Possible to reach the same effect natively (with core packages)?
```

I suppose, for 2021 there must be some method supporting async/await syntax:

```js
// ...
  .pipe(newFeatureOfModernNodeJS(async function (file) {

    await doSomethingAsyncWithFile(file);
    // on fail - same effect as "callback(new Error('...'))" of trough2

    return file; // same effect as "callback(null, file)" of trough2

    // or
    return null; // same effect as `callback()` of trough2
   }))

// ↑ Possible to reach the same effect natively (with core packages)?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is likely a Transform stream, something implemented by the native 'stream' library included with Node.js. I don't know that there is an async compatible version yet, but there is most definitely a callback based one. You need to inherit from the native Transform stream and implement your function.

Here's the boilerplate I like to use:

```js
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;
const util      = require('util');

function TransformStream(transformFunction) {
  // Set the objectMode flag here if you're planning to iterate through a set of objects rather than bytes
  Transform.call(this, { objectMode: true });
  this.transformFunction = transformFunction;
}

util.inherits(TransformStream, Transform);

TransformStream.prototype._transform = function(obj, enc, done) {
  return this.transformFunction(this, obj, done);
};

module.exports = TransformStream;
```

Now you can use this in places you would use through:

```js
const TransformStream = require('path/to/myTransformStream.js');
//...
.pipe(new TransformStream((function (file, encoding, callback) {
    // Do something with file ...
    callback(null, file)
 }))
```